# Getting Unreachable Address Sending UDP Messages

Tags: c#

I am trying to make some UDP communication between 2 different address, so my sending code looks like:

```
 var localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress.Parse("192.168.2.10"), 51111)
 var remoteEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10"), 51111)

 var sender  = new UdpClient (localEndpoint)
 sender.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontRoute, 1);
 sender.Send (request.RawRequest, request.RawRequest.Length, remoteEndpoint) |> ignore
 sender.Close ()
```

As you see those are 2 different address, so I am binding interface address to my client and turning off routing. But when I try this I am getting unreachable network message, but when I try same address families well it works.

I also do broadcast to this destination (that is 192.168.1.2) where endpoint is:

```
new IPEndPoint(IpAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 51111)
sender.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
```

And it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The address family is an array where normally index zero is IPV6 and index one is IPV4.

Comment: I removed family from question

Comment: Get mask for the interface using from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL.  the broadcast address (all 255) is treated different from other IP address.  The mask may be blocking the IP address or sending data to a different interface.